# Powershell Core - How to make linux file type executable

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Is there a powershell core equivalent to the following bash command when running on linux:

```
sudo chmod +x myexec
```

I want to make this file type executable. This is simple to do using bash but I would prefer to use powershell if it is possible.

So far I am using the following command:

```
bash -c "chmod +x myexec"
```

Comment: Just invoke `sudo chmod +x myexec` directly; `sudo` is an external utility, as is `chmod`, so PowerShell has no problem calling them directly.

Comment: As an aside: your command is making a _given file_ executable, not a file _type_.

Comment: Please clarify what platform you're planning to run this on.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Executable flag is a linux/unix term.
... on windows it is not relevant.

Stick with the solution you currently have of invoking the bash command from inside the PS script

Comment: PowerShell core is explicitly platform agnostic. So it is not relevant, if the executable flag is "relevant on Windows" or not. PowerShell Core should enable setting +x via Set-ItemProperty. I haven't had the chance to check the source code if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use next code, it worked very well for my needs i tested on pwsh version 7 on opensuse.

```
function Invoke-Sudo { 
    & /usr/bin/env sudo pwsh -command "& $args" 
}
Invoke-Sudo "chmod +x /usr/bin/filename"
```

I hope this help you!